# Norm of a partition defined by a set, Riemann sum

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-integration, partitions-for-integration

The set $\{1,1.7,2,3.5,5\}$ determines a partition, $P$.

Let $z_1=1$, $z_2=2$, $z_3=3$, $z_4=4$, and $f(x)=\sqrt{4-\left(x-3\right)^2}$.

There’s three things I’m told to find:

- $\lVert P\rVert$
- The Riemann sum $R_P$ of $f$
- And finally I need to find this mess: $$\lim\limits_{\lVert P\rVert \to 0} \sum_{i=1}^n \left(\sqrt{4-\left(z_i-3\right)^2}\right) \Delta x_i$$

---

I have the formula $$\int_a^b f(x) \,dx=\lim\limits_{\lVert P\rVert \to 0} \sum_{i=1}^n f\left(z_i\right) \Delta x_i$$ written down in my notes, but I’m not sure what to do with it (I’m not very strong with sigma notation).

I know that $\lVert P\rVert$ represents the largest subinterval in the set (the norm of $P$), and that this is $1.5$ (between the intervals $\left[2,3.5\right]$ and $\left[3.5,5\right]$). I’ve also calculated the values for each $z$ given to me:

$$f(z_1)=0$$
$$f(z_2)=\sqrt{3}$$
$$f(z_3)=2$$
$$f(z_4)=\sqrt{3}$$

I don’t know what to do with all this information. Any help with figuring this out is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. I believe the word you were looking for is *norm*, not normative -- it means the length of the largest subinterval defined by the partition $P$. You're right in your value for $\lVert P \rVert$. For your second question all you need to do is evaluate the finite sum $R_P = \sum_{i=1}^4 f(z_i)\Delta x_i$.

Comment: As for your third question, you can calculate the definite integral $\int_1^5 f(x)dx$ if you know how. Hint: you can interpret the graph of $f(x)$ as the upper part of a circle of radius $2$, centered in $(3,0)$.

Comment: Thank you very much,@B. Núñez, that is the word I was looking for and I've updated the question to reflect that. For for the second part I got $\sqrt{\frac{243}{25}}+3$, and for the third $2\pi$.